# How i can connect azure MySQL server with my Xamarin forms app?

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, xamarin

**The Problem :**

I have an old C# Windows form application that use Microsoft azure (MySQL) as a database server , i want to build an android app (using Xamarin forms) that fetch data from same MySQL server (Azure) that are used by the C# WFA app .

**The Questions :**

does Xamarin Forms provides such way to do that ?

is there a better approach that i can use ( as a beginner ) to share the same database with two different apps on two different platform ( Desktop and mobile phone in my case) ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to SO!

> Does Xamarin Forms provides such way to do that ?

Simple answer is (unfortunatly): No.

If you want to reuse the exact same database that is stored on Azure with Xamarin Forms, you should expose an API over the web that interacts with your Azure Database. Then your Xamarin Forms app will connect to your API using `HttpClient` class in order to post/fetch data. Xamarin forms supports locally SQLite database engine, that's it. If needed, more info about local DB with Xamarin Forms [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases).

> is there a better approach that i can use ( as a beginner ) to share
>   the same database with two different apps on two different platform (
>   Desktop and mobile phone in my case) ?

Best approach would be definetly to expose a web API that is linked to your Azure DB. In the future, your desktop AND mobile app (and whatever other app) will call you ApiController methods meaning this would be shared code between all your apps.

Hereunder a generic sample method about how to call your API from Xamarin Forms:

```
public static async Task<TResult> GetData<TResult>(string apiTarget)
{
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
           //setup client
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_API_BASE_URI);
           client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 9999999; 
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _TOKEN);
           TResult _Result = default(TResult);
           //make request
           HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiTarget).ConfigureAwait(false);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

               _Result = (TResult)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(content);
           }
           return _Result;
      }
}
```

Happy coding!